# Why the data of paypal webhook notify, event_type and resource.status do not match

Tags: paypal, paypal-webhooks

I simplified the data structure received from paypal callback, why event_type is PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED but resource.status is PENDING

```
{
  "id": "xxxx",
  "event_version": "1.0",
  "create_time": "2022-05-30T06:17:22.994Z",
  "resource_type": "capture",
  "resource_version": "2.0",
  "event_type": "PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED",
  // ...
  "resource": {
    "id": "xxxx",
    "status": "PENDING",
    "status_details": {
      "reason": "PENDING_REVIEW"
    }
    // ...
  },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Captured PayPal payments can be under review for many reasons. If the webhook's details aren't enough for you, examine the payment in [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) and/or have one of the account owners contact PayPal's support.